# How can I add a Json string in a launchsettings.json file in my app and read the values?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-configuration

I have a react front end and c# backend app. I have a launchsettings.json file where i put some configuration.
I want to add a string and read that in my c# app

I have tried adding something like the following in my launchsettings.json file:

```json
"jsondata": 
{
 "value1": "value1data",
 "value2": "value2data", 
 "value3": "value3data"
}
```

So in my C# code I have a value let's say value2, I want to be able to get the Json data and then filter out "value2" and then extract "value2data" to use in my app.

How can I do this in C#?

Comment: Why in launchSetting.json any specfic reason? You have appSettings.json file as well.. There you can easily get with ConfigurationManager.

Comment: I use launchSetting.json as it is a dev environment and thats where it reads them from . When i deploy I put it in the configuration of the app service in Azure.  I retrieve the settings like this :  Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("value") ?

Comment: Yes in launchSettings.json its Environment Variable, you can fetch via that.

Comment: Sorry im missing whatyou are trying to say ? do you have an example of this / How i can set the json file value and read from c# ?

Comment: @Crystal Can I know that which framework application you are using?

Comment: .net 7.0 is the target framework

Comment: Are you asking in general(reading json data) or specifically from launchSettings.json file?

Comment: I am asking can i put a json string as a value in the launchsettings.json file, read that value and then in c# parse it and get some certain values ?

Comment: @Crystal I have set Json string under environmental variables in launchsettings.json and able to retrieve using Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("value"). is this what you are [checking](https://i.imgur.com/goGcqop.png), please [check](https://i.imgur.com/oltwzIr.png).

Comment: Can you share your launchsettings.json file for more understanding.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have added Json string in the **launchsettings.json** file and able to read the values.

- Here, I have taken C# web application and added Json string.

**Program.cs:**

```cs
namespace WebApplication2
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

            // Add services to the container.
            builder.Services.AddRazorPages();

            var app = builder.Build();

            // Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
            if (!app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                // The default HSTS value is 30 days. You may want to change this for production scenarios, see https://aka.ms/aspnetcore-hsts.
                app.UseHsts();
            }

            app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            app.UseStaticFiles();

            app.UseRouting();

            app.UseAuthorization();

            // Read the jsondata environment variable
            var jsonData = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("jsondata");

            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(jsonData))
            {
                var json = JObject.Parse(jsonData);
                var value1 = json["value1"]?.ToString();

                // Pass value1 to the Razor Page
                app.Use(async (context, next) =>
                {
                    context.Items["Value1"] = value1;
                    await next();
                });
            }
            app.MapRazorPages();

            app.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

Here is my **`launchsettings.json`**:

```json
{
  "iisSettings": {
    "windowsAuthentication": false,
    "anonymousAuthentication": true,
    "iisExpress": {
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:54494",
      "sslPort": 44352
    }
  },
  "profiles": {
    "http": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "http://localhost:5001",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "jsondata": "{\"value1\": \"294729729\", \"value2\": \"439849475\", \"value3\": \"84593846\"}"
      }
    },
    "https": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "dotnetRunMessages": true,
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:7181;http://localhost:5001",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "jsondata": "{\"value1\": \"294729729\", \"value2\": \"439849475\", \"value3\": \"84593846\"}"
      }
    },
    "IIS Express": {
      "commandName": "IISExpress",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "environmentVariables": {
        "ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT": "Development",
        "jsondata": "{\"value1\": \"value1data\", \"value2\": \"value2data\", \"value3\": \"value3data\"}"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

- By using `var jsonData = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("jsondata");` able to get the values which is under EnvironmentVariable inside the launchsettings,json.

[image]

Comment: can i make the entry in the file take up 2 lines instead of one ? so this "jsondata": "{\"value1\": \"294729729\", \"value2\": \"439849475\", \"value3\": \"84593846\"}" } to take up 2 lines instead of one as i may have a few entries ?

Comment: Yes you can @Crystal

Comment: How can i do that , is there an example ? thanks

Answer (score 0):

Given you launchSettings.json file looks like this :

```
{
  "profiles": {
    "YourAppName": {
      "commandName": "Project",
      "launchBrowser": true,
      "applicationUrl": "https://localhost:5001;https://localhost:5000",
      "environmentVariables": {
        "CustomSettings": "{\"key1\": \"value1\", \"key2\": \"value2\"}" //add params as you wish here
      }
    }
  }
}
```

In your program.cs file you can access it via the IConfiguration below :

```
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;

    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            IConfiguration config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json") // You may need to adjust the file path
                .Build();
    
            string customSettingsJson = config["CustomSettings"];
          
            dynamic customSettings = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(customSettingsJson);
    
            
            string key1Value = customSettings.key1; // Access individual values
            string key2Value = customSettings.key2; // Access individual values
    
            
            Console.WriteLine($"Key1: {key1Value}, Key2: {key2Value}");
        }
    }
```

Comment: The key should be unique in json. you can add as much as you want with different keys. Appreciate if you can mark the above answer as correct one and give a upvote. thank in advance.